# View tag wiki excerpt on tag page on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-wiki-excerpt, mobile-web

One important thing I feel is missing from the mobile design is the ability to view a tag's excerpt directly on the tag page. I find the excerpts very useful on the main site when I see a tag on a question, but don't exactly know what it's about.

Considering it *is* an excerpt, it won't take up too much room, which is important for a mobile-optimized design). Like on the full website, it should go below the `Questions Tagged [tag]` header, and above the question list. It could even include a `more` link that goes to the corresponding `/tags/[tag]/info` page. Perhaps something like this:

[image: Hooray for mockups!]

Answer (score 1):

**Tag excerpt is now displayed on top of the page in mobile web version**. It has implemented as a part of [Mobile web refresher, part 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239378/mobile-web-refresher-part-3).

Screenshot from iPhone:

[image]