# Mobile version does not show tag information

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, top-users

When I click on a tag (like [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog)), I get usually general information on the tag **and then** the questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog.

But on the mobile version there is no access to info, topusers and the like at all. It is fine that the mobile version is terse, but at least one link "info" in the beginning would be nice.

Comment: Well, you can always browse directly to the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info) but yeah, adding the excerpt to the tagged questions page might be a good idea.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Maybe only one link to the info-page; provided that info page contains all the other links. The big problem currently is that you have to switch to the desktop-version, where you have to left-right scroll to read many texts. (Up-down scrolling **is** cool on mobile devices..)

Comment: [Tag excerpt is now displayed on mobile-web](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239423/). Top users etc is still not available.