# Top users and tag info of a tag in mobile site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, mobile-web

I was using the Stack Exchange mobile site today and opened a tag to view the top-users and tag-info for the tag. I discovered that there was no link to the top users neither was there any place the tag-wiki excerpt was shown.

Also, putting https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/topusers or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info directly in the address bar loads the desktop site.

Can these the top-users and tag wiki excerpt and info be added to the mobile site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile version does not show tag information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155745/mobile-version-does-not-show-tag-information)

Comment: [Tag excerpt is now displayed on mobile-web](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239423/). Top users etc is still not available.